# How can i hide pretty photo gallery on mobile media query?

Tags: css, prettyphoto

Im using pretty photo on my web, it works good, but i find it useless in mobile, so im trying to hide it in the  media query by using display none, but the problem is that im not shure what is it that i have to hide. Thanks!

Comment: hide the div that contains it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657665/disable-prettyphoto-on-small-screens-or-any-a-href-link

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a `div` with a `class` and hide this one:

```
.gallery-container {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .gallery-container {
        display: none;
    }
}
```